# Describing the generator of an evaluation map

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

I'm having a lot of trouble approaching this question:

> Let $a \in \mathbb{C}$ and $S:\mathbb{Z}[x] \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ be a map where $S(f(x)) = f(a)$. Is ker($S$) principal? Describe the generator.

I'm really not sure where to start with this. I know that elements in the kernel will have $a$ as a root, but $a$ is complex and elements in the kernel are integer polynomials, so I'm not sure this helps.

Could I have some hints on how to get started?

Comment: Hint: some elements of $\mathbb{C}$ are algebraic (i.e., are roots of polynomials with coefficients in $\mathbb{Q}$) and some are not.  What is the kernel if $a$ is not algebraic, e.g., $a = \pi$?

Answer (score 0):

$\ker S$ must be principal. Let $i:\mathbb{Z}[x]\to\mathbb{Q}[x]$ be the inclusion map, $E:\mathbb{Q}[x]\to\mathbb C,\ f\mapsto f(a)$ the evaluation map over $\mathbb{Q}[x]$. Since $\mathbb{C}$, and consequently all the subrings of $\mathbb{C}$, is a integral domain, $\ker E$ is a prime ideal of $\mathbb{Q}[x]$. So $\ker E=0$ or $(f)$ with $f$ being a irreducible polynomial of rational coefficients. Note that $S=E\circ i$ and $i$ is injective, thus $\ker S=\ker S\cap\mathbb{Z}[x]=0$ or $(g)$, where $g$ is the primitive polynomial corresponding to $f$. In both cases $\ker S$ is principal.